# How to save PDF format file if I get the Axios response content-type of application-stream?

Tags: javascript, axios, filesaver.js

I would like to save a octet-stream type data to a pdf file, the data is correct as I have tried to use Postman "Send and Save" function to get and open the pdf file successfully.

However, once I call axios request and receive the response from the server, I cannot get the correct pdf file. After I got the pdf file, it seems that the file is broken, can I cannot open it correctly.

Here's the header of the response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdGus.png)

```
        axios.create({
        baseURL: link,
        timeout: 60000,
        headers: {
            Authorization: token
        }
    }).post(apiUrl, {
        .
        .
        .
    }).then(res=>{
        var file_data = res["data"];
        var file_type = res["headers"]["content-type"];
        var blob = new Blob([file_data], {type: file_type});
        saveAs(blob, "Test.pdf")
    });
```

Comment: For further information, I found that the problem may caused with the encoding of the data. As I compared a file that downloaded by Postman and a file that generated by the JS Filesaver.

It seems that some of the character turns into another form, those character just looks like squares. But anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem, it seems that the size of the file is different with the original one, and I make the following changes to receive the data in form of Blob object to solve it.

```
axios.create({
    baseURL: link,
    timeout: 60000,
    responseType: 'blob'
    headers: {
        Authorization: token
    }
}).post(apiUrl, {
    .
    .
    .
}).then(res=>{
    var file_data = res["data"];
    var file_type = res["headers"]["content-type"];
    saveAs(file_data, "Test.pdf");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When downloading binaries with Axios, the format of the data returned by the server needs to be specified with the request. In the case of a PDF file, generally "arraybuffer" needs to be used.

```
axios.get(
      "https://example.com/example.pdf",
      {
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
      }
    );
```

As per the documentation, the valid options are:

```
// `responseType` indicates the type of data that the server will respond with
// options are: 'arraybuffer', 'document', 'json', 'text', 'stream'
//   browser only: 'blob'
//   default: 'json'
```

[Axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api)